# Why can't I draw and update my map correctly?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a Bomber for my school project and this code displays the main menu and the map.

I use Pyqt5, and I tried to self.update() a little bit everywhere but it doesn't change anything.

```py
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from random import *

class Perso:
    def __init__(self,imgName):
        self.vie=1
        self.x=1
        self.y=1
        self.score = 0
        self.imgName=imgName
    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x-=1

    def moveRight(self):
        self.x+=1

    def moveUp(self):
        self.y+=1

    def moveDown(self):
        self.y-=1

class Application(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        super().__init__(argv)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.font=self.setFont(QFont("Arial",14))
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
        p = self.palette();
        p.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(33,53,73))
        p.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53,53,53))
        p.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(142,45,197))
        p.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(255,255,255))
        p.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, QColor(255,255,255))
        self.setPalette(p)

class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.LONG=15
        self.LARG=15
        self.grid=self.initGrid()

    def initGrid(self):
        grid=[]

        case_dep=[(2,1),(1,2),(1,12),(1,13),(2,13),(12,1),(13,1),(13,2),(12,13),(13,13),(13,12)]

        for i in range(self.LONG):
            line=[]
            if (i==0) or (i==self.LONG-1):
                for j in range(self.LARG):
                    line.append(0)
            else:
                for j in range(self.LARG):
                    if (j==0) or (j==14):
                        line.append(0)
                    elif (i%2==0) and (j%2==0):
                        line.append(0)
                    elif (i,j) in case_dep:
                        line.append(1)
                    elif (i,j)==(1,1):
                        line.append(2)
                    else:
                        if(random()<0.80):
                            line.append(3)
                        else:
                            line.append(1)
            grid.append(line)
        return grid

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    def initUI(self):
        # Initialise la fenêtre
        self.setWindow()
        self.player="indien"
        self.stackedLayout = QStackedLayout()

        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MainMenu())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuOptions())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuDifficulte())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuJeu())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuPerso())

        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.stackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.setImage()
        self.setCenter()
        self.show()

    def onClickedPerso(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(4)

    def onClickedDiff(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(3)

    def onClickedJouerNinja(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="ninja"

    def onClickedJouerCowboy(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="ninja"

    def onClickedJouerChevalier(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="chevalier"

    def onClickedJouerIndien(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="indien"

    def onClickedOption(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def onClickedReturn(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def MainMenu(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        midWidth = self.frameGeometry().width()/2
        midHeight = self.frameGeometry().height()/2

        #Bouton pour lancer le jeu
        self.buttonJeu = QPushButton("Jouer")
        self.buttonJeu.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight-50)
        self.buttonJeu.clicked.connect(self.onClickedPerso)

        self.buttonOpt = QPushButton("Options")
        #self.buttonOpt.setFont(font)
        self.buttonOpt.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight)
        self.buttonOpt.clicked.connect(self.onClickedOption)

        self.buttonQuit= QPushButton("Quitter")
        #self.buttonQuit.setFont(font)
        self.buttonQuit.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight+50)
        self.buttonQuit.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonJeu)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonOpt)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonQuit)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)


        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuOptions(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.buttonVolume = QPushButton("Volume")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedReturn)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonVolume)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuPerso(self):
        #ajouter QHBoxLayout avec img perso remière ligne et boutons de choix 2e ligne qui lance la difficulte
        widget = QWidget()
        images=QWidget()
        buttons=QWidget()

        self.hLayout1=QHBoxLayout()

        imgNinja=QLabel()
        imgIndien=QLabel()
        imgChevalier=QLabel()
        imgCowboy=QLabel()

        imgNinja.setPixmap(QPixmap("../img/personnages/ninja/ninja.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgIndien.setPixmap(QPixmap("../img/personnages/indien/indien.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgChevalier.setPixmap(QPixmap("../img/personnages/chevalier/chevalier.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgCowboy.setPixmap(QPixmap("../img/personnages/cowboy/cowboy.png").scaled(100,100))

        imgNinja.setMargin(15)
        imgIndien.setMargin(15)
        imgChevalier.setMargin(15)
        imgCowboy.setMargin(15)

        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgNinja)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgIndien)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgChevalier)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgCowboy)

        self.hLayout1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        images.setLayout(self.hLayout1)

        self.hLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        self.buttonNinja = QPushButton("Ninja")
        self.buttonIndien = QPushButton("Indien")
        self.buttonChevalier = QPushButton("Chevalier")
        self.buttonCowboy = QPushButton("Cowboy")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.buttonNinja.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerNinja)
        self.buttonIndien.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerIndien)
        self.buttonChevalier.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerChevalier)
        self.buttonCowboy.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerCowboy)
        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedReturn)


        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonNinja)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonIndien)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonChevalier)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonCowboy)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.hLayout2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        buttons.setLayout(self.hLayout2)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"
        self.styleSheet2 = "buttonReturn {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 30px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        vLayout=QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.addWidget(images)
        vLayout.addWidget(buttons)
        self.vLayout.setSpacing(5)
        widget.setLayout(vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuDifficulte(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        #essayer QHBoxLayout pour afficher btns horizontalement

        self.buttonFacile = QPushButton("Facile")
        self.buttonNormal = QPushButton("Normal")
        self.buttonDifficile = QPushButton("Difficile")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonFacile)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonNormal)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonDifficile)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.buttonFacile.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonDifficile.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedPerso)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuJeu(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.setRenderArea())

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)
        return widget

    def setImage(self):
        image = QImage("../img/Imagefond/MainBackground3.jpg")
        size = image.scaled(QSize(self.frameGeometry().width(),self.frameGeometry().height()))

        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10,QBrush(size))
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def setCenter(self):
        # Place la fenêtre au milieu de l'écran
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setWindow(self):
        width = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().width()
        height = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().height()
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bomberboy")
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Aucun événement")


    def setRenderArea(self):
        self.renderArea = RenderArea(self.player)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.renderArea)
        return self.renderArea


    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text()+' est préssé')
        print("cliqué")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key=event.key()
        print(key)
        if key==Qt.Key_Left:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche gauche")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Right:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche droite")
            print("right")
            self.renderArea.movePlayerRight()
            print("right done")
            self.update()
            print("update done")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Up:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche haut")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Down:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche bas")

        elif key==Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.onClickedReturn()

class RenderArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,player, parent=None):
        super(RenderArea,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.caseWidth=50
        self.caseHeight=50
        self.setMap()
        self.player=Perso(player)

    def initUI(self):
        self.pen = QPen(QColor(125,155,155))
        self.pen.setWidth(3)
        self.brush = Qt.NoBrush

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        self.painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        self.drawMap(self.painter)

    def setMap(self):
        self.map= Map()


    def drawMap(self,painter):
        self.originX = (self.frameGeometry().width()/2)-(self.caseWidth*self.map.LARG/2)
        self.originY = (self.frameGeometry().height()/2)-(self.caseHeight*self.map.LONG/2)

        for i in range(self.map.LONG):
            for j in range(self.map.LARG):
                if(self.map.grid[i][j]==0):
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
                    painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap("../img/Blocs/Obsidienne.png").scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))

                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==1):
                    painter.setBrush(Qt.gray)
                    painter.drawRect(QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight)))
                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==2):
                    url="../img/personnages/"+self.player.imgName+"/"+self.player.imgName+".png"
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*self.player.x),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*self.player.y)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
                    self.playerImg=painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap(url).scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))

                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==3):
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
                    painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap("../img/Blocs/wall.png").scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight,Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,))

    def movePlayerRight(self):

        print(self.player.x,self.player.y)
        print(self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y])
        if (self.player.x+1<self.map.LARG-1 and self.map.grid[self.player.x+1][self.player.y]==1):
            self.map.grid[self.player.x+1][self.player.y]=2
            self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y]=1
            self.update()
            print("affect",self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y])

app = Application(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But whenever my map is displayed, if I open another tab, the program stops with a QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter on backingstore paint device and a core dumped.

Comment: I added the class Map, is that enough ?

Comment: I did, but I'm not really sure what to provide you with since there are a lot of files I did, let me know if this is enough

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry, I grouped all my classes now so If you use this code it should create the same problem

Comment: what are `movePlayerUp`, `movePlayerDown` and `movePlayerLeft`?

Comment: The same as movePlayerRight, self.player.x and self.player.y are updated to go up, down or left, but I did not add them here because I tested with movePlayerRight and the problem is there already

Comment: Correct your code so that we have no doubts (we do not know what you know), if you consider it unnecessary then delete that part or patch it to work.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I corrected it

Comment: Try adding the line `self.painter.end ()` in the `def paintEvent (self, event):` method.

Comment: I think that worked actually! I’ll let you know

Comment: It works perfectly fine, the map shows and updates normally, so thank you all :D

Comment: "I added the class Map, is that enough?" Yes and no. You made the example complete but not minimal. Now you have to throw out all that is not essential for the problem you have. Btw. that's also a very good programming exercise.

Comment: @S. Nick I think that deserves and answer and some rep ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line self.painter.end () in the def paintEvent (self, event):

```
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from random import *

class Perso:
    def __init__(self,imgName):
        self.vie=1
        self.x=1
        self.y=1
        self.score = 0
        self.imgName=imgName
    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x-=1

    def moveRight(self):
        self.x+=1

    def moveUp(self):
        self.y+=1

    def moveDown(self):
        self.y-=1

class Application(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        super().__init__(argv)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.font=self.setFont(QFont("Arial",14))
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
        p = self.palette();
        p.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(33,53,73))
        p.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53,53,53))
        p.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(142,45,197))
        p.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(255,255,255))
        p.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, QColor(255,255,255))
        self.setPalette(p)

class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.LONG=15
        self.LARG=15
        self.grid=self.initGrid()

    def initGrid(self):
        grid=[]

        case_dep=[(2,1),(1,2),(1,12),(1,13),(2,13),(12,1),(13,1),(13,2),(12,13),(13,13),(13,12)]

        for i in range(self.LONG):
            line=[]
            if (i==0) or (i==self.LONG-1):
                for j in range(self.LARG):
                    line.append(0)
            else:
                for j in range(self.LARG):
                    if (j==0) or (j==14):
                        line.append(0)
                    elif (i%2==0) and (j%2==0):
                        line.append(0)
                    elif (i,j) in case_dep:
                        line.append(1)
                    elif (i,j)==(1,1):
                        line.append(2)
                    else:
                        if(random()<0.80):
                            line.append(3)
                        else:
                            line.append(1)
            grid.append(line)
        return grid

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    def initUI(self):
        # Initialise la fenêtre
        self.setWindow()
        self.player="indien"
        self.stackedLayout = QStackedLayout()

        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MainMenu())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuOptions())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuDifficulte())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuJeu())
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.MenuPerso())

        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.stackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.setImage()
        self.setCenter()
        self.show()

    def onClickedPerso(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(4)

    def onClickedDiff(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(3)

    def onClickedJouerNinja(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="ninja"

    def onClickedJouerCowboy(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="ninja"

    def onClickedJouerChevalier(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="chevalier"

    def onClickedJouerIndien(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.perso="indien"

    def onClickedOption(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def onClickedReturn(self):
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def MainMenu(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        midWidth = self.frameGeometry().width()/2
        midHeight = self.frameGeometry().height()/2

        #Bouton pour lancer le jeu
        self.buttonJeu = QPushButton("Jouer")
        self.buttonJeu.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight-50)
        self.buttonJeu.clicked.connect(self.onClickedPerso)

        self.buttonOpt = QPushButton("Options")
        #self.buttonOpt.setFont(font)
        self.buttonOpt.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight)
        self.buttonOpt.clicked.connect(self.onClickedOption)

        self.buttonQuit= QPushButton("Quitter")
        #self.buttonQuit.setFont(font)
        self.buttonQuit.move(midWidth - 50,midHeight+50)
        self.buttonQuit.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonJeu)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonOpt)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonQuit)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)


        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuOptions(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.buttonVolume = QPushButton("Volume")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedReturn)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonVolume)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuPerso(self):
        #ajouter QHBoxLayout avec img perso remière ligne et boutons de choix 2e ligne qui lance la difficulte
        widget = QWidget()
        images=QWidget()
        buttons=QWidget()

        self.hLayout1=QHBoxLayout()

        imgNinja=QLabel()
        imgIndien=QLabel()
        imgChevalier=QLabel()
        imgCowboy=QLabel()

        imgNinja.setPixmap(QPixmap("img1.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgIndien.setPixmap(QPixmap("img2.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgChevalier.setPixmap(QPixmap("img3.png").scaled(100,100))
        imgCowboy.setPixmap(QPixmap("img4.png").scaled(100,100))

        imgNinja.setMargin(15)
        imgIndien.setMargin(15)
        imgChevalier.setMargin(15)
        imgCowboy.setMargin(15)

        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgNinja)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgIndien)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgChevalier)
        self.hLayout1.addWidget(imgCowboy)

        self.hLayout1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        images.setLayout(self.hLayout1)

        self.hLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        self.buttonNinja = QPushButton("Ninja")
        self.buttonIndien = QPushButton("Indien")
        self.buttonChevalier = QPushButton("Chevalier")
        self.buttonCowboy = QPushButton("Cowboy")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.buttonNinja.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerNinja)
        self.buttonIndien.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerIndien)
        self.buttonChevalier.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerChevalier)
        self.buttonCowboy.clicked.connect(self.onClickedJouerCowboy)
        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedReturn)


        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonNinja)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonIndien)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonChevalier)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonCowboy)
        self.hLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.hLayout2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        buttons.setLayout(self.hLayout2)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"
        self.styleSheet2 = "buttonReturn {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 30px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        vLayout=QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.addWidget(images)
        vLayout.addWidget(buttons)
        self.vLayout.setSpacing(5)
        widget.setLayout(vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuDifficulte(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        #essayer QHBoxLayout pour afficher btns horizontalement

        self.buttonFacile = QPushButton("Facile")
        self.buttonNormal = QPushButton("Normal")
        self.buttonDifficile = QPushButton("Difficile")
        self.buttonReturn = QPushButton("Retour")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonFacile)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonNormal)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonDifficile)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReturn)

        self.buttonFacile.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonDifficile.clicked.connect(self.onClickedDiff)
        self.buttonReturn.clicked.connect(self.onClickedPerso)

        self.styleSheet = "QPushButton {background : #e85941; border-radius: 10px; font: bold 28px; border-color: white; padding: 6px; margin-right: 10px;}"

        widget.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)

        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        return widget

    def MenuJeu(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.setRenderArea())

        widget.setLayout(self.vLayout)
        return widget

    def setImage(self):
#        image = QImage("../img/Imagefond/MainBackground3.jpg")
        image = QImage("im.png")
        size = image.scaled(QSize(self.frameGeometry().width(),self.frameGeometry().height()))

        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10,QBrush(size))
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def setCenter(self):
        # Place la fenêtre au milieu de l'écran
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setWindow(self):
        width = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().width()
        height = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().height()
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bomberboy")
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Aucun événement")


    def setRenderArea(self):
        self.renderArea = RenderArea(self.player)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.renderArea)
        return self.renderArea


    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text()+' est préssé')
        print("cliqué")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key=event.key()
        print(key)
        if key==Qt.Key_Left:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche gauche")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Right:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche droite")
            print("right")
            self.renderArea.movePlayerRight()
            print("right done")
            self.update()
            print("update done")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Up:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche haut")
        elif key==Qt.Key_Down:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Touche bas")

        elif key==Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.onClickedReturn()

class RenderArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,player, parent=None):
        super(RenderArea,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.caseWidth=50
        self.caseHeight=50
        self.setMap()
        self.player=Perso(player)

    def initUI(self):
        self.pen = QPen(QColor(125,155,155))
        self.pen.setWidth(3)
        self.brush = Qt.NoBrush

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        self.painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        self.drawMap(self.painter)
###
        self.painter.end()                                    # <----------------------


    def setMap(self):
        self.map= Map()


    def drawMap(self,painter):
        self.originX = (self.frameGeometry().width()/2)-(self.caseWidth*self.map.LARG/2)
        self.originY = (self.frameGeometry().height()/2)-(self.caseHeight*self.map.LONG/2)

        for i in range(self.map.LONG):
            for j in range(self.map.LARG):
                if(self.map.grid[i][j]==0):
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
                    painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))

                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==1):
                    painter.setBrush(Qt.gray)
                    painter.drawRect(QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight)))
                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==2):
#                    url="../img/personnages/"+self.player.imgName+"/"+self.player.imgName+".png"
                    url="icono.png"                    
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*self.player.x),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*self.player.y)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
                    self.playerImg=painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap(url).scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))

                elif(self.map.grid[i][j]==3):
                    r=QRect(QPoint(self.originX+(self.caseWidth*i),self.originY+(self.caseHeight*j)),QSize(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight))
#                    painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap("../img/Blocs/wall.png").scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight,Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,))
                    painter.drawPixmap(r,QPixmap("img0.png").scaled(self.caseWidth,self.caseHeight,Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,))

    def movePlayerRight(self):

        print(self.player.x,self.player.y)
        print(self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y])
        if (self.player.x+1<self.map.LARG-1 and self.map.grid[self.player.x+1][self.player.y]==1):
            self.map.grid[self.player.x+1][self.player.y]=2
            self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y]=1
            self.update()
            print("affect",self.map.grid[self.player.x][self.player.y])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]